# C++ Opencv load CSV file as cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, csv

I save a cv::Mat as a CSV file which works fine, but when I go to load it and convert it back into a cv::Mat something is being corrupted. When I print out the contents of the cv::Mat they are different from that of the csv file. And when I show the Mat object I get a wide white window.

```
cv::imwrite("cameraFrame1.jpg", frame);
outFile.open("cameraFrame1.csv");
outFile << cv::format(frame, "CSV") << std::endl;
outFile.close();

...

CvMLData mlData;
mlData.read_csv("cameraFrame1.csv");
const CvMat* tmp = mlData.get_values();
cv::Mat img(tmp, true);
tmp->CvMat::~CvMat();

std::cout << "img: " << img << std::endl;

cv::namedWindow("img");
cv::imshow("img", img);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

Edit:

I am not at all attached to this method, if there is a better way to save an image to CSV and then read it in as such I will gladly move to that. The point of this is to save the image as raw data, most likely in a database, which could then be opened again in matlab, python, c++ etc.

Comment: Why don't you save it as a png file with imwrite()? That is losslessly compressed and can be read back almost anywhere (Matlab, Python, libpng...). It can even be stored in a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to set both the image depth and channels, which is the cv::Mat type in c++, as well as the dimensions

```
cv::imwrite("cameraFrame1.jpg", frame);
outFile.open("cameraFrame1.csv");
outFile << cv::format(frame, "CSV") << std::endl;
outFile.close();

...

CvMLData mlData;
mlData.read_csv("cameraFrame1.csv");
const CvMat* tmp = mlData.get_values();
cv::Mat img(tmp, true);

// set the image type
img.convertTo(img, CV_8UC3);

// set the image size
cv::resize(img, img, cv::Size(320, 256));

tmp->CvMat::~CvMat();

std::cout << "img: " << img << std::endl;

cv::namedWindow("img");
cv::imshow("img", img);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

Comment: why do you need that `resize`? For a colored image, you're saving a csv file with 320*3 numbers each row, and when you read it back and resize it, it will become a grayscale image.

Comment: Sorry that this is incredibly late but why do you think that the image will become greyscale? The convert to is converting to 3 channels and there's nothing in the [cv::resize docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=resize#void%20resize(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20dsize,%20double%20fx,%20double%20fy,%20int%20interpolation)) to suggest that it's changing the channels of the image.