# How to save an OpenCV 3.2 image to a csv file and then load it to display?

Tags: c++, csv, opencv

I am trying to perform some operations on an image in which i have to save an image to csv file and later load it to display .I'm working on opencv 3 in which the CvMLData doesn't seem to work as shown in this example [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020548/c-opencv-load-csv-file-as-cvmat) I guess the functionality has changed in 3.2 version.

```
CvMLData mlData;
mlData.read_csv("cameraFrame1.csv");
const CvMat* tmp = mlData.get_values();
cv::Mat img(tmp, true);

// set the image type
img.convertTo(img, CV_8UC3);

// set the image size
cv::resize(img, img, cv::Size(320, 256));

tmp->CvMat::~CvMat();

std::cout << "img: " << img << std::endl;

cv::namedWindow("img");
cv::imshow("img", img);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the code you have shown is for OpenCV 2, with the machine learning stuffs all being moved in OpenCV 3. It's probably worth having a read over the [Transistion Guide](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html)

The code and images below show how you can write a matrix out to a csv file, read it back in, resize it and display all three matrix out to windows.

[image]

With this code:

```
#include <fstream>
void examplethree()
{
    cv::Mat mat = imread("mypic.png");
    imshow("window", mat);
    ofstream outputFile("cameraSamples.csv");
    outputFile << format(mat, cv::Formatter::FMT_CSV) << endl;
    outputFile.close();

    cv::Mat img;

    cv::Ptr<cv::ml::TrainData> raw_data = cv::ml::TrainData::loadFromCSV("cameraSamples.csv", 0, -2, 0);
    cv::Mat data = raw_data->getSamples();
    // optional if you have a color image and not just raw data
    data.convertTo(img, CV_8UC3);
    img = img.reshape(3); //set number of channels

    // set the image type
    img.convertTo(img, CV_8UC3);

    // set the image size
    cv::resize(img, img, cv::Size(320, 256));

    //std::cout << "img: " << img << std::endl;

    cv::namedWindow("img");
    cv::imshow("img", img);
    cv::imshow("mat", mat);
    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i was trying to use cv::ml::TrainData of opencv3 which did not work

Comment: Yes, sorry I misunderstood that you were trying to move from 2 to 3, I have updated the blurb at the beginning of my answer to reflect your question better :)